# When I run the code it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

When I run the code it returns:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";


async function fetchPerson(url){

  await fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => { 
      return data
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })    
}

async function printNames() {
  console.log("Before");
  const person1 = await fetchPerson(URL+ "1");
  const person2 = await fetchPerson(URL+ "2");
  console.log(person1.name);
  console.log(person2.name)
  console.log("After all"); 
}

printNames(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const URL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/";

async function fetchPerson(url){
return await fetch(url).then(res=>res.json());
}    
async function printNames() {
    console.log("Before");
    const person1 = await fetchPerson(URL+ "1");
    const person2 = await fetchPerson(URL+ "2");
    console.log(person1.name);
    console.log(person2.name)
    console.log("After all"); 

}

printNames(URL);
```

Comment: Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

In **fetchPerson** function, write **return** instead of **await**.

```js
async function fetchPerson(url){
  return fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => { 
      return data
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });    
}
```